# eth0 is not present in interfaces still it connects at boot

Tags: networking, ip

I am connected through my eth0 to my university network. The c onnection works with no problems. Still i wander why the eth0 is not present in interfaces.
I run ubuntu 12.04 ans use shorewall
Thanks
Vanja

Answer (score 1):

Run `ifconfig`. You should get a list of interfaces and data about them such as IP addresses.